# Return value of fgets()

Tags: c, io, fgets

I have just recently started working with `I/O` in `C`. Here is my question - 
I have a file, from which I read my input. Then I use `fgets()` to get strings in a buffer which I utilise in some way. Now, what happens if the input is too short for the buffer i.e. if the first read by `fgets()` reaches `EOF`. Should `fgets()` return `NULL`(as I have read in `fgets()` documentation)? It seems that it doesn't and I get my input properly. Besides even my `feof(input)` does not say that we have reached `EOF`. 
Here is my code snippet.

```
char    buf[BUFSIZ];
FILE    *input,
        *output;

input   = fopen(argv[--argc], "r");
output  = fopen(argv[--argc], "w");

/**
 *  If either of the input or output were unable to be opened
 *          we exit
 */
if (input == NULL) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Failed to open file - %s.\n", argv[argc + 1]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (output == NULL) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Failed to open file - %s.\n", argv[argc + 0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), input) != NULL) {
    ....
}

/**
 *  After the fgets() condition exits it is because, either -
 *      1) The EOF was reached.
 *      2) There is a read error.
 */
if (feof(input)) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Reached EOF.\n");
}
else if (ferror(input)) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Error while reading the file.\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that `feof(input)` will only return true *after* attempting to *read past* EOF. It doesn't tell you that you are *at* EOF.

Comment: Can you explain that in the context of the example above. Suppose, `fgets()` reads only `100 bytes` (`BUFSIZE` is 512), should `fgets()` return `NULL`?

Comment: Ok, now I realise how dumb my comment was; anyways I get what you mean. How do I check if EOF was reached?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation for `fgets()` does not say what you think it does:

From my manpage

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than `size` characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed  to  by  `s`.   Reading
>   stops  after an `EOF` or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('`\0`') is stored
>   after the last character in the buffer.

And later

> `gets()` and `fgets()` return `s` on success, and `NULL` on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

I don't read that as saying an `EOF` will be treated as an error condition and return `NULL`. Indeed it says a `NULL` would only occur where `EOF` occurs when *no* characters have been read.

The POSIX standard (which defers to the less accessible C standard) is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html and states:

> Upon successful completion, `fgets()` shall return `s`. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and `fgets()` shall return a null pointer. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, `fgets()` shall return a null pointer, and shall set `errno` to indicate the error.

This clearly indicates it's only going to return a `NULL` if it's actually at `EOF` when called, i.e. if *any* bytes are read, it won't return `NULL`.

Comment: Can you explain `feof()` part, why doesn't it print anything. `EOF` has been reached right?

Comment: `feof()` tests the end of file indicator, which is only set if you've already had an error where you have attempted to read past the end of the file. It does not (confusingly) indicate you are at the end of the file.

Comment: @yadav_vishal I had already explained `feof` behavior in my prior comment to your original post.

Comment: @mbratch Yeah, I read it again **carefully** and understood what you meant, but how do I check if I reached `EOF`. If not by `feof()` then how?

Comment: You do the `fgets()` again, you will get `EOF`. That's the normal way to test.

Comment: @yadav_vishal what abligh said. You continue using `fgets` until you see it return `NULL` to end the loop. At that point, `feof` should be TRUE since the `NULL` means `fgets` attempted to read past EOF.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! I used an `if()`, should've used a `while()`.

Comment: @mbratch At that point, `feof` will only be nonzero if no error occured. For example, if `fgets` encountered an i/o error during the read, `fgets` will return `NULL` and `feof` will return zero.

Comment: @Brandin yes, that is true. There still needs to be a check for error.

Comment: "it's only going to return a `NULL` if it's actually at `EOF` when called" Small clarification: If a rare input error occurs, `NULL` is also returned - so some characters may have been read prior to or as part of the error.