# fgets reading more char than it should

Tags: c, arrays, string, sizeof, fgets

I'm developing a code where the user will type several paragraphs and it will stop reading when the user begin a paragraph with "END". The code will manipulate the string by counting each letter and showing a graph and blah blah blah, but this is irrelevant to the question.
The thing is: which paragraph must have no more than 1000 characters.

A smaller version of the code is the following (considering I just want to storage 5-char-string - even though I'll expand that).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char paragraph[5];

  for ( ; ; )
  {
    fgets(paragraph, 5, stdin);

    if (paragraph[0]=='E' && paragraph[1]=='N' && paragraph[2]=='D')
    { return 0; }

    printf("%s", paragraph);
  }

  return 0;
```

My problem is: if I type more than 5 characters, the printf function still prints more than 5 characters, I don't know why. I've already checked everything I could possible check.

Help a beginner like me, please.

Comment: Your `printf` doesn't print a newline or similar, so you'll read five characters, print them, and read another five and print them straight after. You're reading 5 at once, it's just you're doing it multiple times. Try printing a character before `%s` to verify if this is the case.

Comment: *"I've already checked everything I could possible check."* - except the return value from `fgets`.

Comment: It types more than 5 characters because `fgets` does not discard the rest of the line: it reads *all* the input.

Comment: I've already check, WITHIN MY KNOWLEDGE*

Answer (score 1):

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
>   stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
>   A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

So when entering more than **4** characters (newline included) only 4 is read and the rest stays in the buffer ready to be read next `fgets`.

Your `printf` will not print any newline in this case and will be called multiple times, making it look like printing more than 4 characters.

As suggested in comments, try `printf("[%s]", paragraph);` to see the individual `printf` calls.

Comment: Yeah, I tried printing "%s\n" and now I see it. But now I don't know two things: (1) how to get rid of the remaining characters I don't want and (2) how can I possible print more than 5 chars if my array has only 5 positions. Jesus... maybe coding is not for everyone or I'm stupid.

Comment: 1) See http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html. 2) print multiple times or increase your array size and read into next position in the array. Hope it helps, keep trucking.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code in the following way and you'll *immediately* see what actually happens with the `fgets()` function when you enter more characters than the `size` of your buffer. It doesn't read from the keyboard, but from the `stdin`buffer. These SO posts may also be interesting for you to read:[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679063/return-value-of-fgets), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919009/how-to-read-from-stdin-with-fgets). Enjoy the demo and be sure to thoroughly read the `man` pages.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char paragraph[5];

  for ( ; ; )
  {
    printf("Enter the string: \n\t");

    if(fgets(paragraph, 5, stdin) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", paragraph);

    if (paragraph[0]=='E' && paragraph[1]=='N' && paragraph[2]=='D')
        return 0;    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But how can I print only the 5 chars? It seems so easy, but I just can't do it. By the way, where are the chars storaged? How can the printf function print more than 5 chars if my array only has 5 positions?

Comment: Please, run this demo and you'll **_immediately_** see where's the problem in your code. Also, take a look at the answer by @Nightcrawler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use strstr in string.h because it's cleaner.

```
if (strstr(paragraph, "END"))
 return 0;
```

instead of

```
if (paragraph[0]=='E' && paragraph[1]=='N' && paragraph[2]=='D')
 return 0;
```